Telegram link display an Array instead of a string inside <button> tag on WP single page
I have posted an issue with getting user's data (telegram username) on this link which is resolved by changing telegram1 to email2 in functions.php:
Could not get WP user data for a custom field on user's Profile page
That is the first issue.
Now I face the second issue which is The display of the of Telegram string obtained from user profile's page of WP inside a button tag is displayed as an Array even it is a string with Telegram URL (https://t.me/) in front of that variable:

I retrieve telegram username from a custom field on WP user profile's page with these codes:
 $telegram_input1 = get_the_author_meta('email2', $user_ID);  
 $curauth_telegram1 = str_replace('@', '', $telegram_input1);    // remove @ from telegram username above which is email2
 echo 'https://t.me/' . $curauth_telegram1;                    // Display telegram URL with username outside <a> tag



The above displays correct telegram URL with username correctly like this:
    https://t.me/james444   (If $curauth_telegram1 is james444)
    


Test inside a link tag which is working correctly:
 <a href="<?php echo 'https://t.me/' . $curauth_telegram1; ?>" target="_top">Chat with me</a>


I insert:
 echo 'https://t.me/' . $curauth_telegram1;



inside link tag which is inside a button tag like this:
    <?php
    if ($curauth_telegram1 != "") { ?>
          <button class="btn chat"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots" style="color:#892cdc !important;"></i><a href="<?php echo 'https://t.me/' . $curauth_telegram1; ?>" target="_top"> messaging</a></button>
    <?php   } ?>

The above displays an array like this even telegram username is a string as displayed above:
    https://t.me/Array

I think the button tag seems not recognise https://t.me/Array as a string which causes the string variable to become an array?
How can I fix this issue?

No, neither "prefixing" this with a static text literal such as 'https://t.me/', nor the fact that it gets output "inside a link", can change the type of a PHP variable. Please make a var_dump($curauth_telegram1); directly in your template where you output those links, and see what that shows.

And FYI, you can not nest a into button, or vice versa - that is not allowed in HTML, since they are both considered "interactive elements", and as such they must not be nested.

thanks for very quick advice. I have just updated my post. It is not link tag causing such issue which I tested; it is  tag causing such issue or other symbol I put inside it? Can u please advise how to fix this? Cheers

Nothing you output before or after this, should be able to cause this. Please do as instructed, and check what the variable actually contains at this point, using var_dump.

Yes, I will try using only button tag to see if it is working

Again - it is very unlikely (actually, quite impossible), that any of the HTML you output before, after or around this, has anything to do with this.

it works inside , so the issue is what you advised; both  and  tags should not be nested inside each other. Do I need to use Javascript to make that button a link click?

"it works inside , so the issue is what you advised" - my advise wasn't regarding the actual problem, and there is absolutely no logical explanation as to why the code you have shown, should behave that way. "Do I need to use Javascript to make that button a link click?" - no, please don't. Use the correct HTML element for the intended purpose. You want to link to a URL here, so you should use a link, not a button. If you want that link to look like a button - then format it accordingly using CSS.

The culprit is  tag which I found out causing that string variable to be an Array. When I removed it from inside  tag, it works well. Yes, it is good practice not to nested  inside  and vice versa. I ll use javascript for a button click. Many thanks

"The culprit is  tag which I found out causing that string variable to be an Array." - there is no logical explanation for why that should have been the culprit, either. (And unless you can provide us with an actually reproducible example, I'm still gonna say, that wasn't actually it. https://3v4l.org/8fWiH with your code from above, and a string value for the variable, does not produce the result you say it was.)

Thank you for your help. I still have issue with showing Array; I am a bit crazy as I have spent long hours debugging codes. This line of codes works well: Chat

but this one using if statement to check does not work: if (!empty($curauth_telegram1)) {
Chat
}

both have exactly the same codes except the second one using if statement to check if it is not empty. I have spent 2 hours figuring out this bug, and cannot find a solution. Can u please have a quick check. Many thanks

I found a bug due to me defining variable in a theme's file not correctly - text instead of string. I ll update the answer shortly
